# Win 2008 R2 SSTP Certificate

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl-certificate, sstp

I have a Win 2008 R2 server running on AWS EC2 and need the ability to VPN to it. PPTP isn't an option given EC2 firewall restrictions (no GRE routing).

I am planning to setup SSTP and it is my understanding that a self-signed cert is ***not*** an option.

So

1. Will one of Godaddy's "Standard" SSL certs work for SSTP? (Only
   $13. I am the only person connecting to this via Win7.)
2. Can I buy a wildcard cert or does it need to be host specific?
   (*.mydomain.com vs bla.mydomain.com)
3. Any other considerations?

Comment: Do you have a source for your belief that you cannot use a self-signed certificate? I can't find anything to corroborate that, nor have I ever encountered an SSL-based technology that wouldn't allow a self-signed certificate.

Comment: I haven't used SSTP, but this article seems to indicate a self-signed cert is possible.  http://artisticcheese.blogspot.com/2009/04/instructions-how-to-enable-sstp-vpn-s.html  Even if it isn't possible, that doesn't mean you have to pay for the cert, you could almost certainly setup a CA using one of many OpenSSL based tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be wildcard.

The server and the client both have to trust the issuing root, so you could use a free [CACert](http://www.cacert.org/) and add the root to server and client (as a trusted root in Computer Certificate store), or the Godaddy route is fine too.

Comment: Finally got it all working and it does work with a self signed cert. The key was specifying the correct cert from RRAS via server properties.

Comment: Great.  I'm assuming you copied the server self-signed cert to the client's trusted roots?

Comment: Bret, yes, copied the server self signed cert back to the client.